# The applicationis keeping to use old DLL file

Tags: windows, dll

When I open the application I get [an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCPO3.png). The error say that there is no **comctl32.dll** in folder "C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.19041.1110_none_c0da534e38c01f4d".

I opened this folder and it's empty.

But in a similiar folder with a bit different name
"C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.1110_none_a8625c1886757984" I found comctl32.dll file.

How do I can tell the programme from which folder it should take the *.dll file?
CLIPSWIN.EXE is not an application compiled by me but I have to use it to end my educational project.

On the professor's PC, it works well

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the .dll to the folder the program is looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot, unless you are able to compile the source code of the application against a newer version of the DLL.

When an application is compiled with a specific version of a DLL, it notes all the "entry points" needed to instantiate objects and call methods within the DLL. This process is called Binding or Linking. If a newer version of the dll with new or altered method entry points is used, the program won't be able to link to that DLLs objects and methods.

if you can get the proper version of the dll you want, you can just drop it in the executable's folder as Gantendo mentioned. Executables will generally search their own location for libraries before looking other places.

Answer (score -2):

A little stranger, if you faced a similar problem as me, there is the solution.

Run these commands in cmd.exe executed with administrator rights.

```
DISM  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
DISM /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth 
SFC /SCANNOW
```

And restart the computer. After that, it should be fixed.